# System.MissingMethodException from HttpDocumentRetriever..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Spent a day baffled by this exception from an ASP.NET application after adding/updating libraries, on certain machines.

```
System.MissingMethodException Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever..ctor(System.Net.Http.HttpClient)'.
```

The IdentityModel.Protocols assembly is there, and the constructor checks out with dotpeek.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was solved by installing .NET Framework 4.7.2. The machines having the problem had .NET Framework 4.6.2.